# Подключение сurl к Qt в Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c, qt, curl

Я пишу в `Qt` на `Си` и мне нужно подключить `curl` к моему проекту, но у меня это не получается сделать. Я скачал архив, в `.pro` файле прописал `INCLUDEPATH += .../include` и теперь я могу подключить `<curl/curl.h>` (раньше этого не мог сделать). Но когда я вызываю функции, допустим, `curl_easy_init()`, то у меня вылезает ошибка, что компилятор не знает такую функцию. В чем дело, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: @VTT к сожалению, у меня нет файлов с .lib или .a :(

Comment: .so тоже пойдет

Comment: @VTT и такой нет. Приплыли...

Comment: Ну тогда поставьте...

Comment: У вас "не знает функцию" компилятор или линковщик? Это же разные вещи...

Comment: `sudo ldconfig -p | grep curl`, пока не появятся `.so` файлы работать не будет. Ну и нужно указать линковщику что вам нужна эта библиотека. В .pro файле `LIBS += -lcurl` видимо